# Having an issue when configuring HotModuleReplacement in webpack 2

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-2, hot-module-replacement

I'm trying to integrate HotModuleReplacement and following [this](https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-boilerplate/tree/next) boilerplate, but is not working with my webpack configuration.

The "issue" I am having is in the `output.publicPath` entry. Following the example I mentioned, that line is "*necessary for HMR to know where to load the hot update chunks*", but when I include it in my webpack config it gives me this error `GET http://localhost:3000/ 404 (Not Found)`. If I don't include it, webpack compiles everything successfully, but HMR does not work even though when I look at the console I get this

```
[WDS] App hot update...
dev-server.js:45 [HMR] Checking for updates on the server...
log-apply-result.js:20 [HMR] Updated modules:
log-apply-result.js:22 [HMR]  - ./src/components/App.js
dev-server.js:27 [HMR] App is up to date.
```

Below is `webpack.config.js` file.

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: [
    'react-hot-loader/patch',
    'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3000',
    'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
    './src/index.js'
  ],
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    publicPath: '/static/'
  },
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  module: {
    rules: [
      { test: /\.(js)$/, exclude: /node_modules/, use: ['react-hot-loader/webpack', 'babel-loader'] },
      { test: /\.css$/, use: [ 'style-loader', 'css-loader' ] },
      { test: /\.(png|jpg)$/, loader: 'file-loader?name=images/[name].[hash].[ext]' },
            { test: /\.woff(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'file-loader?name=fonts/[name].[hash].[ext]&mimetype=application/font-woff'},
            { test: /\.woff2(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,loader: 'file-loader?name=fonts/[name].[hash].[ext]&mimetype=application/font-woff'},
            { test: /\.ttf(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'file-loader?name=fonts/[name].[hash].[ext]&mimetype=application/octet-stream'},
            { test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'file-loader?name=fonts/[name].[hash].[ext]'},
            { test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'file-loader?name=images/[name].[hash].[ext]&mimetype=image/svg+xml' }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({ template: 'public/index.html', favicon: 'public/favicon.ico' })
  ],
  devServer: {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 3000,
    historyApiFallback: true,
    hot: true
  }
}
```

What am I missing?

These are my project dependencies just in case

```
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^15.5.4",
    "react-dom": "^15.5.4",
    "react-prop-types": "^0.4.0",
    "semantic-ui-css": "^2.2.10",
    "semantic-ui-react": "^0.68.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-loader": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.4.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-1": "^6.24.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.1",
    "file-loader": "^0.11.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.28.0",
    "react-hot-loader": "next",
    "style-loader": "^0.17.0",
    "webpack": "^2.5.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.4.5"
  }
```

**EDIT**

I got it working. I changed `publicPath` to `publicPath: '/'` and added `{"modules": false}` to my `.babelrc` file

Below is my `.babelrc` file

```
{
  "presets": [["env",{"modules": false}], "react", "stage-1"]
}
```

I guess I have a new question, what does `{"modules": false}` mean? what it is used for?

Answer (score 0):

.babelrc is the configuration for the babel transpiler.

"Setting this to false will not transform modules.".

source: https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-es2015/#options